# How to get to know Visual Studio version from vcproj and sln to execute?

Tags: visual-c++

How to know the visual studio version needed to execute the C++ application from vcproj and sln file?

The .vcproj file has below details,

```
<VisualStudioProject
ProjectType="Visual C++"
Version="8.00"
```

The .sln file has below details

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.32802.440
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
```

Please help me.

Comment: Why do you want to know that?

Comment: My client shared  their old code.  they are migrating the code from  C++ to C# now. We need to understate the existing code for migrating. They dont now how to execute, I need to give details on how to execute.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#release-dates-and-build-numbers

Comment: Are you sure that you need the *minimum* version? I recently "helped" someone who failed to install the VS2015 runtime (a library requirement), by asking "Have you tried using the 2022 version?". And it just worked!

Comment: @Hans Passant, the version="8.0.0" in vcproj refers what?

Comment: The .vcproj format is very old, fairly sure that 8.0.0 is [VS2005 vintage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio#History).

Comment: Some Apis may  be deprecated. Have you tried opening the sln file with VS2022?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia says that Visual C++ 8.0 is part of Visual Studio 2005, which is really ancient. You should not bother trying to work with that. You should open the project in the Visual Studio you have available, let it upgrade the project, and just build it.

If there are some build errors due to C++ standard having changed, just fix those minor errors, and continue with your main effort, which is to port it all to C#.

If you find it too expensive or time consuming to upgrade the whole C++ project to C#, you may discover it's easier to combine the old C++ code and some new C# code. Some of C++ code may need to be converted to C++/CLI, but only the interface that new C# code needs to work with.